# Exporting TCP Connection Latency in Resource Monitor

Tags: windows-10, tcp, performance-monitor, resource-monitor

In Resource Monitor in Windows 10 I am looking to monitor and log out the latency of for a particular TCP connection.

In Performance Monitor there is the option to create a data collector set but I haven't been able to find process specific attributes which I could capture and log.

Is what I'm hoping to do possible? Or should I use another tool to capture the TCP connection latency?

[image]

Comment: See if the following tool is helpful with you:https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_latency_view.html

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. You can mark that as an answer and I'll mark as solution.

Comment: I am pleased to know it is helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the NetworkLatencyView tool is helpful with you:

> NetworkLatencyView is a simple tool for Windows that listens to the TCP connections on your system and calculates the network latency (in milliseconds) for every new TCP connection detected on your system. For every IP address, NetworkLatencyView displays up to 10 network latency values, and their average. The latency value calculated by NetworkLatencyView is very similar to the result you get from pinging to the same IP address.
> NetworkLatencyView also allows you to easily export the latency information to text/csv/tab-delimited/html/xml file, or copy the information to the clipboard and then paste it to Excel or other application.

For your reference:

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_latency_view.html

Comment: This is definitely the best option I have come across. However it doesn't monitor the latency over time and only really captures the latency when the connection is made. A related app AppNetworkCounter also by Nirsoft is really good to look at network usage up and down